# Stripe.js complaining about being included twice

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe.js, but I'm getting the following warning in the console:

`It looks like Stripe.js was loaded more than one time. Please only load it once per page.`

The javascript is only on the page once, and the network tab of Developer Tools confirms that the script was only downloaded once, yet I'm still getting the above error, and the `Stripe` object is undefined. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: please [don't argue with the console](https://i.imgflip.com/15vep7.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was my error. The stripe script was only run one time, but I had another javascript object called `Stripe` which was being defined before the stripe.js script had loaded.

Comment: The javascript object was within the same file?

Answer (score 1):

try this please, for me it works

```
componentWillMount() {
        const stripeExists = document.getElementById('stripev3');
        if (!stripeExists) {
            const stripeScript = document.createElement('script');
            stripeScript.src = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';
            stripeScript.async = true;
            stripeScript.id = 'stripev3';
            document.head.appendChild(stripeScript);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Carlos, where did you added this function, Within the stripe.js script?

Comment: Carlos, it would be really helpful to know where to place his code.